# How to benchmark test java applications?

Tags: javascript, java, testing, benchmarking

I'm currently working on a project that talks on source to source compiler optimisation, what tools are there available for me to benchmark test java and JavaScript applications?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Java is a completely different thing than JavaScript. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: SO is not for recommending tool which are seen as opinion based. If you have a coding problem include the code and what the issue is you are having.

Comment: Never the less for Java, I suggest looking at JMH.